# com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$CaptchaRequiredException

Tags: java, gdata-api, gdata

I am getting below error while executing the gdata api sample code. I am new to the api . Please let me know the resolution for the same. Where i need to to put the captcha and how.

> SEVERE: Authentication Error: Captcha required
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$CaptchaRequiredException:
>   Captcha required  at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:623)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:500)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.setUserCredentials(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:346)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:362)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:317)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:301)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.audit.AuditService.(AuditService.java:77)
>     at AuditSampleClient.main(AuditSampleClient.java:100)

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.audit.AuditService;
import com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.audit.MailBoxDumpRequest;
import com.google.gdata.data.TextConstruct;
import com.google.gdata.data.appsforyourdomain.AppsForYourDomainException;
import com.google.gdata.data.appsforyourdomain.generic.GenericEntry;
import com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;

public class google_data {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            export_data();
    }
    public static void export_data()
    {
        MailBoxDumpRequest request = new MailBoxDumpRequest();
        request.setAdminEmailAddress("-----");
        request.setUserEmailAddress("----------");

        Calendar beginDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        beginDate.set(2011, Calendar.AUGUST, 1, 4, 30);
        request.setBeginDate(beginDate.getTime());

        Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        endDate.set(2011, Calendar.AUGUST, 30, 20, 0);
        request.setEndDate(endDate.getTime());

        request.setIncludeDeleted(true);
        request.setSearchQuery("in:chat");
        request.setPackageContent("FULL_MESSAGE");

        AuditService service = null;
        try {
            service = new AuditService("-----", "------", "------", "-------auditapp-v1");
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GenericEntry mailboxDumpEntry = null;
        try {
            mailboxDumpEntry = service.createMailboxDumpRequest(request);
        } catch (AppsForYourDomainException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        TextConstruct requestId = mailboxDumpEntry.getSummary();
        System.out.println(requestId.toString());
        //String status = mailboxDumpEntry.getStatus();
        //String numberOfFiles = mailboxDumpEntry.getNumberOfFiles();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:

http://code.google.com/googleapps/faq.html#handlingcaptcha

Why do I keep getting CAPTCHA errors even after I unlock the administrator account?

```
Please verify in your code that you are specifying your full administrator email address e.g. "admin@domain.com" instead of just "admin".
```

Answer (score 2):

It means exactly what it says - the service requires the user to solve a CAPTCHA before you can use an automated login again.

The exception should include a URL for the relevant CAPTCHA. From the [client login](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/clientlogin.html#RecallAuthToken) user guide:

> A failure response from ClientLogin contains an error code and a URL to an error page that can be displayed to the user. If the error code is a CAPTCHA challenge, the response also includes a URL to a CAPTCHA image and a special token. Your application should be able to solicit an answer from the user and then retry the login request.

The URL is available through the [`getCaptchaUrl()`](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/GoogleService.CaptchaRequiredException.html#getCaptchaUrl%28%29) method.